# Excel - Close hidden worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, macros

When I open Workbook 1.xlsm, Workbook 2.xls will open automatically but hidden in the background.

How do i adjust my macro so that when I close Workbook 1.xlsm, both instances of Excel will all close. i.e. Hit the close button on Workbook 1.xlsm will also close Workbook 2.xls completely.

Also, if i can save and close Workbook 2.xls, that would be great.

My code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\....\2016\Current BSL, Branch Stock, Whouse Stock, On Order.xls", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `ThisWorkbook` module, you can use the `Workbook_BeforeClose` procedure to close `Workbook_2.xls` before `Workbook_1` closes.

We pass `True` into the `.Close` method so that it saves the workbook before closing it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Workbooks("Workbook_2.xls").Close True

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the your code. When `True`, Excel will ask me to save as for the Workbook 2.xls. When set to `False` Excel does not close fully. By this i mean, an instance of Workbook 2.xls is still left behind. The sheet for Workbook 2.xls is closed but the application still remains. #